# NullReferenceException in XNA when creating a Color array

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to do pixel-perfect hit detection for a game I am making, and to do so I am using color arrays of the textures.

```
bool DetectHitOnAttack(Player player, Enemy enemy)
{
    Color[] AttackColors = new Color[player.AttackTexture.Width * player.AttackTexture.Height];
    Color[] EnemyColors = new Color[enemy.texture.Width * enemy.texture.Height];
    player.AttackTexture.GetData<Color>(AttackColors);
    enemy.texture.GetData<Color>(EnemyColors);
}
```

When I call `DetectHitOnAttack` the variables I pass to player and enemy both have non-null values.
The error suggests using the new keyword to create an object instance, but I am already doing that.
If anyone could help me make sense of this that would be great.

Comment: What line throws the error when you debug?

Comment: `player` and `enemy` may be not-null but how about `player.AttackTexture` and `enemy.texture`?

Comment: Oh sorry, the line Color[] AttackColors = new Color[~~~]; gives me the error

Comment: And the textures have values as well.  They are used elsewhere and work fine.

Comment: In that case, AttackTexture, Width , or Height is null.  Just put a breakpoint on that line and make sure each is not null.

Comment: Yes! Thanks David that helped me find my error.